# "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" in python shell

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I wrote a code in django-rest-framework, but got error. My class is -

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')
```

When I wrote "from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer" in python shell I got this error - 
"IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

I searched for the solution, but got nothing. Please somebody help me.

Comment: "I searched for the solution, but got nothing." - exactly what did you try typing into a search engine; what results came up; what did you try changing after reading those pages; and what happened as a result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disclaimer: ignore this answer as it does not respond to the question.

If you paste the following code in a Python shell:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')
```

You'll run into issues because the Python shell will think your class definition ends right after the id line, at the first blank line.

To work around this, you need to remove the empty line:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')
```

Comment: This is wrong, in that OP did not paste the code into the shell, but instead used the shell to `import` the code from a file. The situation you describe would have caused a different error message. This answer could only have fixed the problem by accident, by re-posting the code with proper indentation (OP mixed spaces and tabs).

Comment: Indeed, not sure how I missed that. Can't delete the answer as I need at least  another vote